# What options/configs do we have while using Google Proto Js compiler for styling enums

Tags: javascript, enums, protocol-buffers

Right now our proto definition for a particular case looks like this

```
option java_package = "com.packageName.proto.device";
option java_outer_classname = "PlatformEntity";

/* Supported Platforms */
enum Platform {
    iOS = 1;
    Android = 2;
    Web = 3;
    Backend =4;
}
```

The compiled js code looks something like this

```
var jspb = require('google-protobuf');
var goog = jspb;
var global = Function('return this')();

goog.exportSymbol('proto.Platform', null, global);
/**
 * @enum {number}
 */
proto.Platform = {
  IOS: 1,
  ANDROID: 2,
  WEB: 3,
  BACKEND: 4
};

goog.object.extend(exports, proto);
```

As I understand, the [style guide suggests](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style#enums) enum value names to be defined with CAPITALS, but we don't want to do that as it will corrupt our existing data and/or reports.

Would appreciate if someone could point out a way to enforce the existing styling here during compilation?